# What is the significance of REMOTEID attribute in Tally Voucher XML File?

Tags: tally

I'm working on a utility to import my statements in Tally as a voucher.
What I wish to achieve is that if in future I send the same entry by mistake, Tally should be able to identify it as Duplicate and overwrite it instead of creating a new voucher entry. I found REMOTEID attribute in the XML file and looks like that can be used to identify unique ids but I couldn't find a comprehensive documentation of Tally's XML format for Import and Export.

Answer (score 2):

Think of `remoteid` as primary key of a table. Yes, it can be used to Add/update records in tally.

When importing vouchers in Tally, if the remote ID is same as existing voucher, it will fire an `Update`. If not found or if remoteid is not provided, it will fire `Create` command.

[image: tally xml export]

I am using this remote id to do create/update in my app on [Excel to Tally](https://tally.jamku.app/)

Answer (score 0):

The master ID of a voucher is the unique attribute. I'm not sure if it is the same as remote ID (a simple check in Tally versus XML should prove this). Knowing this, you could check for it and continue your workflow.